# SQL regex expression for text before pipe

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I need an oracle regex to fetch data before first pipe and after the last slash from the text before pipe.

For example, from the string:

```
test=file://2019/13/40/9/53/**2abc123-7test-1edf-9xyz-12345678.bin**|type
```

the data to be fetched is:

```
2abc123-7test-1edf-9xyz-12345678.bin
```

Comment: You will need to identify which SQL DBMS you're using; the answer will probably be different in each of them.  Also, your text shows slashes, not backslashes.  If you're going to work with regexes, you _must_ know the difference.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the pipe (or the first pipe, if there is more than one) will come after all the slashes? If not, what is the desired output? What is the desired output if there are no pipes in the input? (I assume you are guaranteeing that there is at least one slash; if not, explain what should happen if there are no slashes also.) Finally, explain why you need a regular expression, when this can probably be done much more efficiently with standard (non-regexp) functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Oracle :

```
select regexp_substr(col,'[^|/]+\.\w+',1,1,'i')
from (
    select 'test=file://2019/13/40/9/53/2abc123-7test-1edf-9xyz-12345678.bin|type=app/href|size=1234|encoding=|locale=en_|foo.bar' as col 
    from dual
) q
```

[MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) & [TeraData](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/vzc1472241131255.html) also have such REGEXP_SUBSTR function, but haven't tested it on those.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `^.+?/([^/]+?)\|` starts at the beginning of the string, skips over every character, then captures all non-slash characters, between the last slash and the first pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '/([^/|]+)\|', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Live [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30f3a132841dc5db452521adb83afe6d)

Regex breakdown:

- `/` Match literally
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `[^/|]+` Match anything except slash and pipe, at least one character
- `)` End of CG #1
- `\|` Match a pipe

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\/]*?(?=\|)
```

- `[^\/]*?` — matches any character that is not a backslash
- `(?=\|)` — positive lookahead to match a vertical line

Comment: Oracle does not support positive lookahead